# Logarithmic Spiral- N-gon

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

In the mice problem, also called the beetle problem, $n$ mice start at the corners of a regular $n$-gon of unit side length, each heading towards its closest neighboring mouse in a counterclockwise direction at constant speed. The mice each trace out a logarithmic spiral, meet in the center of the polygon, and travel a distance $$d=\frac{1}{1-\cos\big(\frac{2\pi}{n}\big)}$$

Does anybody know where can I find a proof of the formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the $n$-gon is centered at the origin. Pick any mouse and let $\phi$ be the constant angle between the mouse's instantaneous direction of travel (i.e., the tangent line to the spiral) and the radial line from the origin. Then the [equation in polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) of a mouse's trajectory is
$$
r = a\exp(-b\theta)
$$
where $\tan \phi = \frac 1b$ and $a$ is the distance to the origin at the start (so $a$ is the distance from center of $n$-gon to any vertex). Check that $\cos\phi=\sin\frac\pi n$ for a regular $n$-gon, and that $\sin\frac\pi n= \frac1{2a}$ if the $n$-gon has unit side length. The arc length of the path traveled by the mouse is then
$$
d\stackrel{(*)}={a\over{\cos\phi}} = \frac1{2\sin^2\frac\pi n} =\frac1{1-\cos\frac{2\pi}n}.
$$

(*) **Proof of arc length**: The arc length in polar coordinates is
$$
\int_{\theta=0}^\infty\sqrt{r^2+\left({dr\over d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta
$$
which in the logarithmic spiral case simplifies to
$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{1+b^2}\left[a\exp(-b\theta)\right]\,d\theta=a{\sqrt{1+b^2}\over b}.$$
The conclusion follows from $${\sqrt{1+b^2}\over b}=\sqrt{\frac1{b^2}+1}=\sqrt{\tan^2\phi +1}=\frac1{\cos\phi};$$
the cosine is positive since $0<\phi<\frac\pi 2$.